# Need Help on .... Select Where Date NOT BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Hope someone can tell ..

```
Table A                  Table E
Id  |  Date              Id  |  Start_date  |  End_date
 1     2012-12-10         1     2012-12-09     2012-12-10
 2     2012-12-11         2     2012-12-12     2012-12-14
```

The Result that I'm hoping ..
    2012-12-11

This is the code that I think might work to select date from Table A that not in Table E ranga date...

```
SELECT * FROM `A` 
WHERE `A`.`DATE` NOT BETWEEN (SELECT `E`.`DATE_START` FROM `E`) AND (SELECT `E`.`DATE_END`       
FROM `E`);
```

but unfortunately not, the subquery return more than 1 row.

I wonder how??

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to get by running

SELECT `E`.`DATE_START` FROM `E`

Earliest start date in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all records from A that are not inside any of the date ranges in E, get the records that are within the date ranges, and select the ones not in that result:

```
select *
from A
where Id not in (
  select A.Id
  from A
  inner join E on A.Date between E.Start_date and E.End_date
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion it works very well ... thank you again :D

Comment: This would work, but I'm not sure that it's the best way as the intermediate result set from the join between the date sets could get very large.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Yes, you would have to check what it actually does if there is a lot of data. The query planner might not actually create an intermediate result at all.

Comment: is there another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You wonder how the subquery returned more than one row? That's because there's more than one row in the table matching your query.

If you want one row, you'll need to limit the query a little more, such as with:

```
select `e`.`date_start` from `e` where `e`.`id` = 1
```

---

If you want all dates in A that are not contained in *any* date range in E, one way to do it is to get a list of the A dates that *are* contained within a range, and then get a list of dates from A that aren't in *that* list.

Something like:

```
select date
from   a
where  date not in (
           select a.date
           from   a, e
           where a.date between e.start_date and e.end_date
       )
```

Putting this through the excellent [phpMyAdmin demo](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/index.php) site as:

```
create table a (id int, d date);
create table e (id int, sd date, ed date);
insert into a (id, d) values (1, '2012-12-10');
insert into a (id, d) values (2, '2012-12-11');
insert into e (id, sd, ed) values (3, '2012-12-09', '2012-12-10');
insert into e (id, sd, ed) values (4, '2012-12-12', '2012-12-14');
select d from a where d not in (
    select a.d from a, e where a.d between e.sd and e.ed
    );
```

results in the output:

```
2012-12-11
```

as desired.

Comment: Hi, thank for your opinion, but I need to select record from table A where the date not in range of start date and end date in in Table E....... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the Id in table A is the same as the Id in table E :

```
SELECT *
FROM A, E
WHERE A.Id = E.Id
AND A.Date NOT BETWEEN E.Start_Date AND E.End_Date
```

Comment: hi thanks for your suggest, but the result take lowest and the highest from table E. I've allready update my question that include some data in it ..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here is the set of records in A where there does not exist a record in B for which the date in A is between the begin and end dates in B.

Therefore I'd suggest that you structure the query in that way.

Something like ...

```
 Select ...
 From   table_A
 Where  not exists (
          Select null
          From   table_b
          Where  ...)
```

Depending on the join cardinality of the tables and their sizes you may find that this performs better than the "find the rows that are not in the set for which a John exists" method, aside from it being a more intuitive match to your logic.